# C lua function crash

Tags: lua, lua-api

I have made a C module for lua as a dll that I load in Lua using the `package.loadlib` function. The module is supposed to use `luaL_loadstring` to execute some lua code from a string. My lua script is run by an application I didn't code myself, and my module is supposed to extend the functionality of the application. When using `luaL_loadstring` and `lua_pcall` on the result the application crashes on some strings, especially those using functions that call some C functions defined by the application (Note that it doesn't crash on all of the C defined functions, just some of them). It works fine on the strings it doesn't crash on, and on those that it does crash on I can use push the result from loadstring back to lua and execute it just fine there, showing that the code itself should be valid.

This is how I call it:

```
lua_getglobal(L, "loadstring");
lua_pushstring(L, msg);
lua_call(L, 1, 1);
lua_call(L, 0, 0);
```

Are there any suggestions for what might cause these crashes?

Comment: Compile Lua with assertions enabled (define `LUA_USE_APICHECK`) and try running it again.

Comment: It didn't change anything sadly. I still get crashes.

Comment: Run it in a debugger and see where it crashes. We can't do anything without more info.

Comment: The application has anti debugger measurements and the script+module runs fine through my own lua.exe. I am guessing there is some way the application deals with some lua calls that makes it crash. But I understand that it would be hard to diagnose without more info, but thank you for the effort anyway. I might try contacting the developer.

Comment: Provide the assertion error messages